# How to printf "unsigned long" in C?

Tags: c, printf, long-integer, unsigned, format-specifiers

I can never understand how to print `unsigned long` datatype in C.

Suppose `unsigned_foo` is an `unsigned long`, then I try:

- `printf("%lu\n", unsigned_foo)`
- `printf("%du\n", unsigned_foo)`
- `printf("%ud\n", unsigned_foo)`
- `printf("%ll\n", unsigned_foo)`
- `printf("%ld\n", unsigned_foo)`
- `printf("%dl\n", unsigned_foo)`

And all of them print some kind of `-123123123` number instead of `unsigned long` that I have.

Answer (score 667, accepted):

`%lu` is the correct format for `unsigned long`. Sounds like there are other issues at play here, such as memory corruption or an uninitialized variable. Perhaps show us a larger picture?

Comment: Oops, `%lu` worked this time. Thanks. Something else must have happened before and it didn't work.

Comment: @bodacydo: If you've got a bug, it might appear at semi-random... make sure your variable has a valid value before you try printing it.

Comment: Even if the variable is uninitialized, there should be no way printf reaches a point where it could print a minus sign when the format specifier was `%lu`. Technically it's undefined behavior but in reality the variable has an unpredictable value that gets passed to printf which printf then interprets as unsigned. I'm guessing bodacydo's original problem was flow reaching an incorrect printf call instead of the one intended...

Comment: Very helpful, Thanatos. I tried %ul didn't work. How is ul different from lu?

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: %lu is a valid conversion specification, %ul is not. `%lu`, broken out is: `%` — starts a "conversion specification"; `l` — the length modifier, `l` means "[unsigned] long int"; `u` — the conversion specifier, `u` is for an `unsigned int` to be printed out as decimal. Because we gave the length modifier `l`, it then accepts an `unsigned long int`. The letters *must* be in that order: percent, length, conversion. (There are a few more options, such as width and precision, that you can add. *See the man page*, as it documents all this precisely!)

Comment: %ul will just print unsigned (with %u), and then the letter "l" verbatim. Just as "%uw" will print unsigned, followed by letter "w". % starts the convspec, u (or some other character, like d, s, c...) ends it.

Answer (score 59):

For **int** `%d`

For **long int** `%ld`

For **long long int** `%lld`

For **unsigned long long int** `%llu`

Answer (score 44):

- `%lu` for **unsigned long**
- `%llu` for **unsigned long long**

Comment: Yoda convention: "unsigned long" "(l)ong (u)nsigned" is.

Answer (score 26):

Out of all the combinations you tried, `%ld` and `%lu` are the only ones which are valid printf format specifiers at all. `%lu` (long unsigned decimal), `%lx` or `%lX` (long hex with lowercase or uppercase letters), and `%lo` (long octal) are the only valid format specifiers for a variable of type unsigned long (of course you can add field width, precision, etc modifiers between the `%` and the `l`).

Comment: %ld will work fine till the value of std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()/2.  

  Above that %ld will print wrong value(negative value).

Comment: @KaushikAcharya: No, above that it's UB. And it's arguably even UB before that, since `printf` is specified to require the exact correct argument types without the allowances that `va_arg` would have.

Answer (score 15):

The correct specifier for unsigned long is `%lu`.

If you are not getting the exact value you are expecting then there may be some problems in your code.

Please copy your code here. Then maybe someone can tell you better what the problem is.

Answer (score 13):

The format is `%lu`.

Please check about the various other datatypes and their usage in printf [here](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/printf.html)

Comment: Various nonstandard behavior is documented there without marking it as nonstandard. POSIX is the easiest-to-access online standard for printf; extensions beyond ISO C are marked with the "CX" tag:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html

Answer (score 11):

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long d;
    scanf("%llu",&d);
    printf("%llu",d);
    getch();
}
```

This will be helpful . . .