# How to print an unsigned long int with printf in C?

Tags: c, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to printf “unsigned long” in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209909/how-to-printf-unsigned-long-in-gcc)

I have my number like so...

```
int unsigned long number = 600851475143;
```

I am trying to print it with `printf()`. Every time I try, I get a warning by the compiler.

I've tried `%uld`, `%ld` and Googling hasn't seemed to find me the answer.

I'm learning C, but have not had to use a `long int` before, so I'm not sure what I should be using.

What is the specifier I am chasing?

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

Comment: you can read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I recommend using standard order (i.e. unsigned long int). `%lu` is the format tag you're looking for.

```
printf("%lu", 5ul);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there was a conventional order. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 10):

```
int unsigned long number = 600851475143LU;
printf( "%lu", number );
```

prints `600851475143`

Comment: don't forget to add `L` to end of that integer.

Comment: Argh, yep.. Thanks for the remark. I just copied it from the posted question.