# Records not updating in C because struct pointer isn't updating

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char item[1000];
} itemset;

void additem(itemset* items,char* thing,unsigned long* numadded){
    memcpy(items->item,thing,1000);
    items++;(*numadded)++;
}

void showitems(itemset* items,unsigned long numitems){
    itemset* p=items;
    unsigned long count;
    for (count=1;count<=numitems;count++){
        printf("%d %s\n",count,p->item);p++;
    }
}

int main(){
    itemset* myitems=calloc(1,sizeof(itemset)*10);
    itemset* itemstart=myitems;
    unsigned long added=0;
    additem(myitems,"Test",&added);
    additem(myitems,"Test2",&added);
    additem(myitems,"Test3",&added);
    printf("Count=%d\n",added);
    showitems(itemstart,added);
    free(itemstart);
}
```

What I'm trying to see on the screen from running this code is:

```
Count=3
1 Test
2 Test2
3 Test3
```

But instead, I see:

```
Count=3
1 Test3
2
3
```

Therefore my additem function isn't working correctly. I find that a fix is to add `myitems++;` right after each function call, but I'm trying to make the same behavior happen inside the additem function so that I won't have to use `myitems++;` outside of the function. What else can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a double pointer for `items`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char item[1000];
} itemset;

void additem(itemset** items,char* thing,unsigned long* numadded){
    memcpy((**items)->item,thing,1000);
    (*items)++;
    (*numadded)++;
}

void showitems(itemset* items,unsigned long numitems){
    itemset* p=items;
    unsigned long count;
    for (count=1;count<=numitems;count++){
        printf("%d %s\n",count,p->item);
        p++;
    }
}

int main(void){
    itemset* myitems=calloc(1,sizeof(itemset)*10);
    itemset* itemstart=myitems;
    unsigned long added=0;
    additem(&myitems,"Test",&added);
    additem(&myitems,"Test2",&added);
    additem(&myitems,"Test3",&added);
    printf("Count=%d\n",added);
    showitems(itemstart,added);
    free(itemstart);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Count=3
1 Test
2 Test2
3 Test3
```

Also, check this: [How to print an unsigned long int with printf in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033018/how-to-print-an-unsigned-long-int-with-printf-in-c), which says that you should use `%lu`, instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to find an answer for me that works and the guy who just answered gave a similar answer too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char item[1000];
} itemset;

void additem(itemset** items,char* thing,unsigned long* numadded){
    memcpy((**items).item,thing,1000);
    (*items)++;(*numadded)++;
}

void showitems(itemset* items,unsigned long numitems){
    itemset* p=items;
    unsigned long count;
    for (count=1;count<=numitems;count++){
        printf("%d %s\n",count,p->item);p++;
    }
}

int main(){
    itemset* myitems=calloc(1,sizeof(itemset)*10);
    itemset* itemstart=myitems;
    unsigned long added=0;
    additem(&myitems,"Test",&added);
    additem(&myitems,"Test2",&added);
    additem(&myitems,"Test3",&added);
    printf("Count=%d\n",added);
    showitems(itemstart,added);
    free(itemstart);
}
```

Comment: I still feel my answer is a better. Does yours compile? :) Good question btw, +1.

Comment: Yes it does or I wouldn't have posted it

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing same pointer in add item function. You would need to pass a pointer to pointer to make it work. Also use strcpy for string copy. And for showitems pass pointer allocated in calloc call as that doesn't cahnge

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass `items` by "reference" as well, not only `numadded`. Or possibly return the new pointer instead.

Comment: By "reference" is C++ way. It doesn't existe in C. You can only give the adress of the variable in C.

Comment: @CaptainWise That's why I put reference within quotations, because C doesn't have it but it can be emulated.