# Too few arguments to function call

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and working through a book called " Sam's Teach Yourself C Programming in One Hour A Day"

One of the Exercise programs in chapter 2 is giving me an error I am too novice to understand.  A little help and clear explanation without pompous sarcasm would be much obliged!  Thank you for your time and consideration.

[image: Exercise Program]

Comment: `fgets(buffer);`  --> `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);`, `%d` --> `%zu`

Comment: For future questions please copy/paste the code and error messages as text (indented by 4 columns so it gets formatted correctly) instead of using a screenshot.  Screenshots can be difficult to read and it is impossible to copy/paste the example code from if someone wants to try out the code locally.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I will follow those instructions for posting from now on.  I truly appreciate your time and consideration.  Cheers!

Comment: @ChristopherPettit totally unrelated, what text editor is that?

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: fgets() expects three arguments. You are giving it one.

So, call it like this:

```
fgets(buffer, 256, stdin)
```

*buffer* is where the input is to be stored, *256* is the size of the buffer, *stdin* is the stream to read from.

Also, [use %lu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209909/how-to-printf-unsigned-long-in-c) instead of %d as the format specifier for unsigned long.

**Edit**:
[Use the z modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family) as `%zu` for the value returned by `strlen`, which is of type `size_t`

Comment: Thank you very much!  I truly appreciate your time.  This worked perfectly.

Comment: [How can one print a size_t variable portably using the printf family?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family)

Comment: No, use `%zu` for the value returned by `strlen`, which is of type `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @Christopher You're welcome. If an answer solved our problem, consider accepting it. And welcome to StackOverflow and programming in general!