# Printf format string issue(PW.BAD_PRINTF_FORMAT_STRING)

Tags: c, printf

```
sprintf(xBuffer,"%l",rootCause)
```

`rootCause` is `unsigned long`

> bad_printf_format_string:invalid format string conversion

```
sprintf(buffId,"Ox%lx Ox%lx Ox%lx", canSnifferMsg.nodeId, canSnifferMsg.index, canSnifferMsg.subindex);
```

what about this? `nodeId`, `index`, `subindex` all are `long`s

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that `%l` is not a valid format string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to printf "unsigned long" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209909/how-to-printf-unsigned-long-in-c)

Comment: what do you mean 'what about this', this code works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: niketa , Do you still have the same problem with `sprintf(buffId,"Ox%ld Ox%ld Ox%ld", canSnifferMsg.nodeId, canSnifferMsg.index, canSnifferMsg.subindex);` ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct format string for unsigned long is `%lu`.
A list of format specifiers can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).
A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209909/how-to-printf-unsigned-long-in-c).

`%lx` is used to get a hex representation of the number. It is therefore irrelevant if it is unsigned or signed as 2's-complement is used instead of a negative sign.

If you want to print a regular long number you can use either `%ld` or `%li` as specified on the first link I sent.

Example:

```
unsigned long a = (unsigned long)(-25);
char buff[100];

sprintf(buff, "%lu %lx %ld", a, a, a);

printf("%s", buff);
```

Output:

> 4294967271 ffffffe7 -25

Comment: sprintf(buffId,"Ox%lx Ox%lx Ox%lx", canSnifferMsg.nodeId, canSnifferMsg.index, canSnifferMsg.subindex); what about this...nodeId ,index,subindex all are long

Comment: @niketa That is for hexadecimal output. Taking a closer look at `printf` man page would be a good starting point.

Comment: "It is therefore irrelevant if it is ... signed as 2's-complement is used instead of a negative sign".  --> Disagree:  Printing a `long` with a negative value using `"%lx"` is undefined behavior UB.  Printing an `unsigned long` with a value > `LONG_MAX` using `"%ld"` is also UB.  I have never seen this UB to be a problem though.

Comment: @chux i have considered this a cast.